# Imported values in Google Sheets from Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Using Google Forms for a quiz...
The quiz is graded /30.
Value is transmitted into Google Sheets.

Cell `C2` displays a value of grade... here, `14/30` (as an example)
Value for cell `C2` reads as `14`

Attempting to get the value of `D2` to show a mark on 100...
`=C2/30` (this should give me `46.6%`) but it returns a value of `0`

Why won't it pick up the value of `C2` as the value `14` it shows in the fx-box?

How can I get it to pick up the value from the cell to then perform more functions?

Answer (score 1):

If the cell values are entered as numbers, then you will be able to perform the functions you are requesting. I would first double-check to ensure that the values that are within the spreadsheet are formatted as numbers.

[image: If formatted as a percentage]

I have had some difficulty with performing basic functions like the one you have presented only to find out that the spreadsheet is not treating the values in the cell as the appropriate type of data.

Next, I would then check the number of decimals the function is being rounded to. If the rounding is to the 0th decimal place, then you will not see a result for the function =14/30. That function would result in the answer of 0.466667, which would be rounded to 0.

[image: If value is formatted as a number and rounded to the 0th decimal place.]

Answer (score 0):

- **`=ROUND(A2/B2*100, 1)&"%"`**
- **`=ROUNDDOWN(A2/B2*100, 1)&"%"`**
- **`=ROUNDDOWN(A2/B2*100, 2)&"%"`**
- **`=ROUND(A2/B2*100, 2)&"%"`**
- **`=TEXT(A2/B2, "#.#0%")`**
- **`=TEXT(A2/B2, "#.#%")`**
- **`=TEXT(ROUNDDOWN(A2/B2, 3), "#.#%")`**

[image]